# How can I add some simple dynamic elements to an otherwise static page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm revamping a site that allows booking of events that run each year. Each event has its own page which is currently entirely static: each page consists of a heading, description, and a list of dates sorted by venue. Each year when new dates become available, someone has to go in and manually change the HTML for each one, an obviously laborious task.

I'd like to automate the process somewhat by having, say, a CSV file that stores the dates (which could be added to piecemeal), and then the page grabs the relevant dates from there when it loads. I have no experience with server-side stuff, but I have a little knowledge of jQuery, and I have a feeling I should be able to do this with AJAX or the like - but how?

Answer (score 2):

I think that ivoszz's idea is the best in your case. If you want to get a database and PHP, you will need a way to get your data into the database itself, which opens a whole new can of worms. Sure, database + server-side frontend is the industry standard, but I feel that it is oversized for your requirements.

It is easier to learn how to display JSON with jQuery, when reading it from a simple text file. You only need to write this code once.

Then, whenever there is a change, you can use a simple workflow: You use Excel to enter the events, using a prerecorded format. Then you export the Excel file as .csv. Use a small program to read the CSV and serialize it to JSON. Copy the ouput to a predetermined location on the server. Everything is ready.

Should somebody else have to update the site in your absence, all they need is Excel, the conversion tool (which is tiny), and the server password. I am posting the code for the conversion tool at the end of this answer.

Alternatively, you can use the code to create an ASP .NET WebForms project. Instead of serializing the objects created by the code, you can make an .aspx page and display the data on it using server-side code. However, this has some disadvantages.

- .net webforms has a steeper learning curve than JavaScript, and the resulting code will probably use server-side controls, which are hard to style with CSS unless you know how to do it right.
- if you are using an inexpensive hosting package instead of your own server, you have to make sure that the provider has the needed .net version on their server. Also, it will probably eat up more space because of all the libraries normally included in .net web projects.
- if the structure of the input data never changes, you can compile the converter once and start treating it as a black box. Any changes to the way stuff is displayed can be made in the JSON-reading code and debugged directly in your browser. For a .net solution, you have to keep an installation of Visual Studio around.
- .net webforms is not a future-proof skill. Microsoft has created a new, more convenient Web technology, .NET MVC, and I wouldn't suggest starting learning the older tech now. On the other hand, it is not a good idea to make this project MVC if you already have a bunch of existing static pages, because MVC cannot mix static and dynamic pages easily. You'll probably be able to use the content, but will have to rewrite the whole routing system and replace every single internal link.

---

Here is the code for a C# appliaction which will convert the csv to JSON. When compiled, place the .exe in the same directory as your csv, called DataSource.csv. Doubleclick it. It will produce a new file called autoOutput.json in the same directory. Each line in the .csv file has to be built in the `event name; venue; date; cost;` format. You can add comments or similar in the Excel to the right of `cost`, they will be discarded. The order of the lines does not matter. As long as an event name is unique, all venues and dates which start with it will be interpreted as belonging to that event. As long as the combination of event name and venue is unique, all dates will be interpreted as being about that event at that venue.

I'm not doing anything with the information about which lines could not be read because they were too short. You can append it to the file, or exchange its contents with the warning. Then the person who does the conversion will have to fiddle with the csv until there are no warnings, or you can try to leave it in the file, but ignore it when loading for dispalying.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; 

namespace ElendilEvents2JSON
{
    public class Event
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public List<EventInVenue> venues { get; set; }

    }

    public class EventInVenue 
    {
        public String VenueName { get; set; }
        public List<EventInstance> Dates { get; set; }
    }

        public class EventInstance
    {
        public String When { get; set; }
        public String Cost { get; set; }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            //read the file 
            List<int> unreadable;
            List<Event> events = readFile(@".\SourceData.csv", out unreadable);

            //write the file using the normal JSON serializer. Will output just everything as a single line. If the data structure is changed, it will output in the new structure. 
            string autoOutput;
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            autoOutput = serializer.Serialize(events); 
            File.WriteAllText(@".\autoOutput.json", autoOutput); 
        }

         public static List<Event> readFile(string path, out List<int> unreadableLines)
        {
            //get the contents out of the file
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path);
            // split each line into an array of strings
            var csv = lines
                .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
                .ToArray();

            //will hold all events 
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            //will hold the numbers of all lines which were OK
            List<int> unreadable = new List<int>();

            //read each line, if you want to skip header lines, change the zero
            for (int lineCounter = 0; lineCounter < csv.Length; lineCounter++)
            {
                string[] line = csv[lineCounter];

                if (line.Length >= 4)
                {
                    string eventName = line[0];

                    Event currentEvent;
                    //if we haven't yet created the event, create it now and add it to the dictionary 
                    if (!events.Select(ev => ev.Name).Contains(eventName))
                    {
                        currentEvent = new Event { Name = eventName };
                        //the venues of the new event are still empty
                        currentEvent.venues = new List<EventInVenue>();
                        events.Add(currentEvent);
                    }
                    else currentEvent = events.Where(ev => ev.Name == eventName).Single();

                    // the same as above: we have the event now, if the current venue isn't yet on its list, enter it, else use the old one
                    string venueName = line[1];
                    EventInVenue currentVenue;
                    if (!currentEvent.venues.Select(ven => ven.VenueName).Contains(venueName))
                    {
                        currentVenue = new EventInVenue { VenueName = venueName };
                        currentVenue.Dates = new List<EventInstance>();
                        currentEvent.venues.Add(currentVenue);
                    }
                    else currentVenue = currentEvent.venues.Where(ven => ven.VenueName == venueName).Single(); 

                    string date = line[2];
                    string cost = line[3];

                    EventInstance currentEventInstance = new EventInstance { When = date, Cost = cost };
                    currentVenue.Dates.Add(currentEventInstance);
                }
                else
                    //if the line was too short
                    unreadable.Add(lineCounter + 1);

            }
            unreadableLines = unreadable;
            return events;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks rumtscho. :)  if I can find out how to use JSON without browsers throwing a security hissy fit, I'm all over it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be with PHP and a mySQL database.  You can add / overwrite the database with a CSV file, but in the long run, you would be better off developing a simple input form to update the database, rather than going through the task of overwriting / updating the mysql database manually, with the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to start learning PHP to do such simple thing. If you know jQuery a little bit, simply add JSON file to your server, eg. `events.json` with this structure:

```
[
  {
     "event": "Event name",
     "description": "description of the event",
     "dates": [
       {
         "date": "20131028",
         "place": "Dublin"
       }, {
         "date": "20131030",
         "place": "London"
       }
     ]
   }, {
       ... another event here with the same structure...
   }
]
```

load it with `jquery.get`, use some templating library (eg. `underscore`) and make simple template inside the page to display events and details. Finally you will have only 2 pages (or maybe only one), `home.html` for displaying the list of events and `event.html` to display details about the event.

Now editing `events.json` adds and changes events on the home page and details pages. This is just a rough example, it needs to be customized according to your requirements.

Comment: Which one do you mean specifically?

Comment: In Chrome, it throws up: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/data.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: This is misunderstanding. You have to place your json file on the same server where your page is located. For local testing download simple static web server and run it on your local directory, for example: <code>http://4pcbr.com/topic/staticme_simplest_web_server_for_serving_static_files</code>, there are also others in Python or node.js. Choose the environment you prefere.

Comment: This is the correct link: http://4pcbr.com/topic/staticme_simplest_web_server_for_serving_static_files

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is a technology that alow a conversation between a client side script and a server side one. So in order to use it you will have to study some server side stuff. JQuery is a client-side script which means it only runs on the client machine at the browser.

I would recommend you to start with php it is simplier to learn and to use. And just to read a file is way to easy to learn as you want.